# Does time based recurring google app script runs forever?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps

I created following app script to run every 15 minutes:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myScript')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
}

function myScript()
{
  // function
}
```

I executed it. The execution log says "Execution completed". I was wondering whether it will execute in the cloud, if shut down my machine. If yes, then how should I stop it? Is

Comment: `was wondering whether it will execute in the cloud, if shut down my machine.` Yes. `If yes, then how **should** I stop it?` (my emphasis). Given that you `created following app script to run every 15 minutes`, there's no reason why you _should_ stop it. OTOH, perhaps you didn't really intend to have the script run every 15 minutes _ad-infinitum_. You can stop it by manually or programmatically deleting or otherwise altering the trigger. To provide a more specific answer, it would help if you would explain why you would want/need to stop it.